# PreSaveAction() in edit list form not working in SharePoint mobile view

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, edit-form

I have customized the **`Edit`** form of a custom list and kept some code in `PreSaveAction()` method. Its obvious that its working with the normal browser mode.

But when I use the same form in mobile device then its not working.

I want to know whether `PreSaveAction()` is still being called if we edit list item from SharePoint App or in mobile view?

If not then is there any alternative to achieve this?